# Tab bar controller is not showing bar button item

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, uitabbarcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I'm new in Objective-C, and even more using storyboards. This being said I'm trying to use a bar button item within UITabBarController and UINavigationController as can you see in the image below.[image]

But once I run the project in simulator this item is not showing. I would appreciate a non programmatically solution if it's posible.

[image]

Comment: And in the simulator it looks like...?

Comment: @SevenBits just not showing, I will attach a screenshot of simulator

Comment: Hm... looks like you're using a nav bar in your interface, but it' being blocked by your navigation controller's nav bar. Try adding `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;` to your viewDidLoad and see what happens...

Comment: Or if you want to hide your view's navigation bar within the view controller's interface builder, perhaps try selecting "top bar" "none" in "simulated metrics."

Comment: @LyndseyScott now is showing the item button, but now the back button "<HOME" is not showing. If I undertand this behavior, you are telling me maybe using navigation controller and tabbarcontroller is not the best aproach?

Comment: <HOME isn't showing because there's no home button on the nav bar in your interface. All I'm saying is you can't use 2 nav bars at once. You either have to add the right-hand button to the nav controller's nav bar programmatically or customize your own nav bar's buttons in the interface.

Comment: @LyndseyScott Ok, I had two nav bars, now I set to none the top bar. Now Im trying to add back button but automatically remove the item button

Comment: @LyndseyScott well i was adding a navigation item and was not wotking, but Bar button item it does! So now i wonder if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, use bar button item.

Comment: @LyndseyScott that's what i'm trying... i can't achieve pop a view with bar button item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I spent a while trying to get the best way to do it I finally did that I should have done since begin. Read official apple [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20140603132210/https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADNavigationControllerClassRef/ADNavigationController/ADNavigationController.html).

**Parameters**

**viewController**
The view controller that is pushed onto the stack. This object cannot be an instance of **tab bar controller** and it must not already be on the stack.

In other words, my approach is just a bad design.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so the way to do this:

When you create your tab view controller. You have to add a navigation controller that  will handle each tab.

Tab View Controller --> navigation controller --> View Controller 1.

Then add the bar button item to view controller 1. Then go ahead and add the segues.

Now, still it won't show up.

But, if you go to your code for your view controller 1: Add a reference from the storyboard of your bar button item into your View Controller 1 file. Then, in ViewWillAppear():

```
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = _btnNewContact;
```

From there, it will show up and the segue you have configured in your storyboard should work perfectly! =)